How do I force logout of an app that I signed in with my Google account?
I downloaded an app for 18+ years old that I had used on a different device and I thought I had used Google oAuth, so I selected that option to log in with. When I realized it was incorrect, I didn't see anywhere to sign out, so I put down a birthday as if I was 8 years old, hoping that would log me out, but it didn't. Now when I open the app it just says you need to be 18 years old to use the app and doesn't have an option to log out.
I tried the following to get logged out of the app, but none have worked:

Deleting the app data and cache
Uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
Restarting the phone
Removing the connection from Google Third-party apps & services

So where on my device is this login actually stored? How can I remove it?

Apps often only allow access to a limited set if functionality compared to the web site it belongs to. Therefore I would try the web site if yin can recover the account, otherwise delete it.

Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, since I deleted the connection from Google Third-party apps & services website, the site doesn't log me in correctly online. It just brings me back to the login page. So I'll have to contact their support if I am unable to figure out where the login cookie (or whatever it is) is stored on my device.
